# Using margin / padding to space <span> from the rest of the <p>

Tags: css, margin, padding, html

Ive got a block of text, and i want to write the authors name and date bellow it in small italics, so i put it in a `<span>` block and styled it, but i want to space the name out a little bit so i applided margin (also tried padding) to the block but it cant get it to work.

Ive made a jsfiddle of the issue - [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/BqTUS/)

The html looks like

```
<p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium.
<br><span>Author Name, Year</span>
</p>
```

The CSS

```
p       {font-size:24px; font-weight: 300; -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;}
p span  {font-size:16px; font-style: italic; margin-top:50px;}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "space the name out a little bit"?

Comment: put a bit of margin-top between the <span> and the rest of the text

Comment: add `display: block` to your span css, the spacing takes effect http://jsfiddle.net/BqTUS/1/

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Overall just add *display:block;* to your span. You can leave your html unchanged.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ps6fjLwk/)

You can do it with the following css:

```
p {
    font-size:24px; 
    font-weight: 300; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased; 
    margin-top:0px;
}

p span {
    font-size:16px; 
    font-style: italic; 
    margin-top:20px; 
    padding-left:10px; 
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: "display:block;" is absolutely the correct and simple situation here.

Comment: If you want a block element as opposed to an inline element, shouldn't you just use a block element like <div>?

Comment: shouldn't it be `display: inline-block;`?

Answer (score 29):

Add this style to your span:

```
position:relative; 
top: 10px;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BqTUS/3/

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for saving me some time.

Answer (score 11):

Try in html:

```
style="display: inline-block; margin-top: 50px;"
```

or in css:

```
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 50px;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `div` instead of `span`, or add `display: block;` to your css style for the `span` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Try `line-height` like I've done here:
http://jsfiddle.net/BqTUS/5/

Comment: By adding `line-height` you won't effect the rest of the flow of your html document. Adding `inline-block` to your element will be force to follow width constraints if addition elements where to follow to the right of your span. You stated you wanted to "space the name out a little bit so i applied margin". Margins will only apply to TOP, BOTTOM etc of your element. Whereas line-height will keep the spacing correct even when your text wraps to the next line. I've 1 UP'd this as the answer as it is technically correct if the text wraps and you if need space between names and each name line.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BqTUS/2/)

HTML:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsa omnis obcaecati dolore reprehenderit praesentium. Nisi eius deleniti voluptates quis esse deserunt magni eum commodi nostrum facere pariatur sed eos voluptatum?

```
</p><span class="small-text">George Nelson 1955</span>
```

CSS:

```
p       {font-size:24px; font-weight: 300; -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;}
p span  {font-size:16px; font-style: italic; margin-top:50px;}

.small-text{
font-size: 12px;
font-style: italic;
}
```